# How do I save terminal output to a external file on another computer?

Tags: pipe

I'm trying to append the output of wifi signal strength and other values in the command `watch -n 1 cat /proc/net/wireless` to an external file in another computer.

Comment: Can you add more information to your question? What OS does the other computer use. Is there any disk sharing between the two computers (NFS, SAMBA etc.)

Comment: I'm sorry is my first question.  My project is as follows I have a raspberry pi rover running rasbian.  I have managed to control it manually but in the way to autonomy I want to be able to track it through WIFI fingerprinting trilateration.  When I first posted the question I was having a hard time connecting remotely to mySQL from my laptop, I was using xampp but now that I changed to wamp I'm able to connect to it.  Now I'm trying to get the output of the command above which tells you signal strength, noise, and link to mySQL server in my laptop

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the computer where you want the output file written can connect to the other computer using ssh, the following command should do what you need

`ssh njj.chickenkiller.com "while [ true ]; do  cat /proc/net/wireless; sleep 1; done" >results_file`

I've used a loop rather than the `watch` command because if you use ssh you cant create a terminal output.
The results are stored in `results_file`.